# How do i make link open in new tab while using css button

Tags: html, css

This is my code right now:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:150%;color:#fa5252;">GOOGLE</a><br><br>
```

and i wanted it to be a button instead so i swapped out my code with the following:

```
<button onclick="window.open='https://www.google.com'" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>GOOGLE</span></button>
```

It looks just like how i want it to but my only issue is that it does not open in a new tab as my previous code did. Is there a way to make so i can keep the button and make it pop out in a new tab?

If needed my css code is:

```
                .button {
                display: inline-block;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background-color: #fa5252;
                border: none;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 200px;
                transition: all 0.5s;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            .button span {
                cursor: pointer;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }
            .button span:after {
                content: '\00bb';
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0;
                top: 0;
                right: -20px;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }
            .button:hover span {
                padding-right: 25px;
            }
            .button:hover span:after {
                opacity: 1;
                right: 0;
            }
```

is it possible if i added `.button a` in css and use a href instead? i tried and it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code..

```
 <button onclick="Open()" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>GOOGLE</span></button>


<script>
    function Open() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this works great thanks! for further clarification, i added the script tag as a standalone tag but i noticed if i put it inside an existing script tag, it works fine. Is separating script tags just a good programming practice or is it necessary function wise?

Comment: It makes your code cleaner, although it can be used as inline also,  as you mentioned, it's good practice to use it in the script. Thank you

Comment: You could also style a link as a button. Which is a much cleaner approach imo

Comment: Styling is always better and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with

```
<input type="button" value="Open Window"
onclick="window.open('http://www.yoururl.com')">
```

Comment: I can click and it pops in a new tab but the css button is not shown, only text

Comment: <input type="button" value="Open Window"
onclick="window.open('http://www.yoururl.com','_blank')">